# Running Python script from Python shell

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, psexec

In a batch file residing in a remote desktop I have simply written "python jwRelay.py"

I want to run the batch file using psexec using the following command:

```
psexec -s -i 2 \\135.20.230.160 -u administrator -p force cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\jwRelayCDV16\SampleCode\Python\relay.bat"
```

The issue is when I run the above command the command prompt in the remote machine quickly pops up and closes (I can see through mstsc). How can I keep the command prompt open if I want to debug the code remotely?

In my laptop after running the above command I get this:

> PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely 
>  Copyright (C) 2001-2014
>   Mark Russinovich 
>  Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> cmd.exe exited on 135.24.237.167 with error code 2.

Is there any other alternative than running the script jwRelay.py in interactive mode in the remote machine?

Comment: If you want the cmd shell to remain open, then use "/k" instead of "/c", e.g. `psexec -s -i 2 \\135.20.230.160 cmd.exe /k python path\to\jwRelay.py`. If you also want Python to remain open in an interactive shell, use `python -i path\to\jwRelay.py`. Also, the  "-u" option will be ignored considering "-s" makes it run as `SYSTEM`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun, I used /k and that worked. In another thread I asked why I had to change -i 1 to -i 2 because psexec suddenly stopped working with -i 1 option. But could not get any answer in the forum. If you can explain it will be helpful.

Comment: To handle simultaneous users the kernel component of the Windows subsystem (win32k.sys) is mapped to a session address space, and the namespace for named kernel objects (e.g. ALPC Port, WindowStation, Event, Mutant, Section) is partially localized to the `\Sessions` object directory (check `accesschk -qso \Sessions`). Prior to Vista (NT 6) the console shared session 0 with system services, but NT 6 isolates session 0 to system services. The "-i" option should default to the console session. Try `psexec \\135.20.230.160 -s cmd.exe` to open a shell to inspect available sessions.

Comment: Thanks eryksun, I will check that

Answer (score 1):

Python 2

```
execfile("./filename")
```

Python 3

```
exec(open("./filename").read())
```

There are probably also several ways to execute code and specific commands, using Python 2 `commands` or better for both `subprocess` which replaced it. Off the top of my head there are [`commands|subprocess`]`.getoutput`, `subprocess.Popen`, `subprocess.call`, etc.